# How to Use Puppet python module in manifest file

Tags: puppet, python

I am writing a puppet manifest file to install python and pymongo.
This python module is installed on the server, link shown below https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stankevich/python

Here is the manifest file I created. But it say unknown class and resource . Please suggest what wrong in the syntax.

```
class { 'python' :
  version           => 'system',
  pip               => 'present'
}

  python::pip { 'pymongo' :
    pkgname         => 'pymongo',
    ensure          => '2.7',
  }
```

It says `Unknown class: 'python` and `Unknown resource type: 'python::pip'`

Thanks,

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: @Craig Watson, I did not installed it, but someone from my team might have installed. When run this command I see the python module is installed.

#  puppet module list | grep python
├── stankevich-python (v1.9.7)
#

Comment: Needs more information. Where is the code you posted located in your filesystem? Where is the `python` directory with the `stankevich-python` module?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `stankevich-python` is not installed in your `modulepath`. Did you run:

```
puppet module install stankevich-python
```

You can check you `modulepath` on Puppet master using:

```
puppet config print modulepath --section master
```